# scrollToRowAtIndexPath not scrolling to inactive/unloaded cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I've noticed that `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` doesn't scroll to cell that are not currently in view, so If I have 100 cells and I need to get to the one at 70, the call to that selector will do nothing.

Is there a way I can get that cell into memory? I already have the cell's index path...

I need to scroll to that position in my app when the user would want to go there.

Thanks for any thoughts!

EDIT: @dasblinkenlight

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide
{
    //Load remote cell here then scroll
    // :( dont know how to load remote cell yet
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow
{
    //Load remote cell here then scroll
    // :( dont know how to load remote cell yet
    //_cellIndexPath gets assigned on didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_cellIndexPath.row inSection:_cellIndexPath.section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT2:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow
{
//Load remote cell here then scroll
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(keyboardWillShowThreaded) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShowThreaded
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keyboardWillShowMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShowMainThread
{
    //Get the cell
    //_textFieldThatHasFirstResponder is a subview in the cell
    //This returns null, probably because the cell is not loaded into memory
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_textFieldThatHasFirstResponder superview];
    NSLog(@"CELL TO SCROLL TO: %@",cell);
    NSIndexPath *indexPathForCell = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForCell atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It *should* scroll to a cell that's outside the visible area. Could you show how you're calling it, and from what method do you make that call?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right, but i have my 8 cells visible, and when I tap eg. the second one, it scrolls fine, but when I tap the 8'th cell thats partially out of view, noting happens, ofcource there is a lot more cells, but not visible, the one's that are invisible dont scroll either.

Comment: Could you also show the part where you call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the keyboard animation combined with the scrolling animation. Perhaps try to perform the scrolling after the keyboard will show animation is finished (i.e.: put scrolling code in separate method and call it by `-performSelector:afterDelay:`)

Comment: Tried that just now, the cell still returns null, I hardcode in the `indexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0`. I can physically scroll to it in the simulator but it returns null :( Only after I have already scrolled to it, then call the `Cell`, then it returns something

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've got the cause of this, see, you have:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathForCell = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; // nil here
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathForCell atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

When you send `indexPathForCell:` for an out-of-view cell it returns nil, so tableView doesn't know where to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement a delegate so that you can call it from the class where you are in, so that is can update the position

Comment: I'm calling it from the class that the UITableView's in (ie. the class thats UITableView's delegate)

Answer (score 0):

> "I've noticed that `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`
>   doesn't scroll to cell that are not currently in view, so If I have
>   100 cells and I need to get to the one at 70, the call to that
>   selector will do nothing. "

No. it is not true. I have just tried with a tableview with 100 rows. The following code works well.

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:78 inSection:0]
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: I dont get it at all either now, the scroll only works for the first 5 cells on the tableview... I've tried all the different UITableViewScrollPositions. If I click the 6+ number cell the keyboard is just infront of it.

Comment: Perhaps your load time is a problem. Look at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2154009?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: see EDIT2 in my OP, changed the code to include some time. Still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding sleep is changing anything. It just delays execution but does not affect the order. Can you check if the index your are passing to scrollToRowAtIndexPath is valid? I remember seeing the same problem myself but it was related to invisible cell. It was impossible to retrieve invisible cell (tableView returned nil) and therefore its index path was nil and thus scrolling failed.
You could store locations of all cells or compute it on the fly and then pass it to

```
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

It's the only solution I can imagine.